# How to solve expressions like $a^b + b^a = 1234$, find $a, b$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I have gone through some basic Google search to find if there is a pattern to solve these kind of questions, but couldn't find any. Hence posting this question here.

How to tackle the below math equation?

> $a^b + b^a = 1234$, find $a, b$, other than the straightforward solution of $1233^1 + 1^{1233}$?

Comment: This is not [tag:linear-algebra]. That being said, are you looking for integer solutions, or real solutions?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: There are infinitely many real solutions.

Comment: $(a,b)=(1/1235,-1)$ is, arguably, another solution: $(1/1235)^{-1}+(-1)^{1/1235}=1235-1=1234$.

Comment: It seems you're looking for integer solutions only. If so it is very easy for computer to enumerate it since we have $0\le a^b\le 1234$
for $a\ge 2$, we could easy to determine that if $a=2$, $b\le 10$, if $a=3$, $b\le \frac{log(1234)}{log(3)}=6.3...$,...

Comment: @ZhaohuiDu, the smaller of $a$ and $b$ is less than $5$, since $5^5\gt1234$, so if the OP is looking for (positive) integer solutions, there's not a lot to check, and it can all be done by hand.

Comment: @Barry it also decreases it because a and b have same parity.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee, excellent point! That rules out $a=2$ and $4$ quickly, since $4\not\mid1234$.